# Using inductive hypothesis on recurrence relation?

Tags: algorithms, recurrence-relation, recursion, master-theorem, induction

I have a recurrence relation as follows

$$T(n) = 2T(\lfloor n/2\rfloor) + n\log(n)$$

Using the induction hypothesis how do I obtain a relation $T(n)\leq E$ such that $E$ contains neither $T$ nor floor operator ($\lfloor\cdot\rfloor$).

Comment: Well, what is your induction hypothesis?  Or are you just asking for an induction-based proof for some bound? If that is the case, do you want an optimal bound? If not, you should be able to prove that $T(n) \leq 2^n$, for example.

Comment: I don't see any induction hypothesis here...

Comment: Would be clearer to write  $E(n)$.

Answer (score 0):

We can open up the recursion to obtain
\begin{align}
T(n) &\leq n \log n + 2\lfloor n/2\rfloor \log \lfloor n/2 \rfloor + 4\lfloor \lfloor n/2 \rfloor/2\rfloor \log \lfloor \lfloor n/2 \rfloor/2\rfloor \\ &\leq
n\log n + n \log (n/2) + n\log (n/4) + \cdots \\ &\leq
n\log n + n\log n + \cdots \\ &= O(n\log^2 n),
\end{align}
since it takes $\Theta(\log n)$ steps to get to the base case.

If you're more careful, you can show that in fact $T(n) = \Theta(n\log^2 n)$.